# Rearrange all the real numbers between $0$ and $1$

Tags: real-analysis

Can we rearrange all the real numbers between $0$ and $1$, denote
 $f(x):(0,1) \rightarrow (0,1)$ (a bijection), such that for $$\forall 0<x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n<1,$$ neither $$f(x_1) <f(x_2) <\dots <f(x_n)$$ nor $$f(x_1)>f(x_2)>\dots>f(x_n)$$ can be hold $(n>3)$?

I'd like to see an answer in particular for $n=4$ and $n=5$.

Comment: Are you looking for a bijection for which that holds for all choices of $x_1\dots x_n$?

Comment: Wow, this is much less easy for the real interval than the rational.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes,thanks

Comment: Is this generally possible for finite/countable sets? It doesn't seem obvious that it should be

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have not thought about it, if not ,can we give a proof for it ?

Comment: I have to think about it :P

Comment: @Kevin Carlson Do you have a reference for the condition for the rational?

Comment: Doesn't the [Erdos-Szekeres theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) say this is impossible (even for the rationals)

Comment: @deinst Thanks, I'm going to see it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As deinst's link has spectacularly shown, there is a direct link between the question of finding a suitable bijection (per your criteria) and Ramsey theory.  Let's start by answering the question on finite sets:

---

Let $X=\{x_1,\dots ,x_N\}\subset \mathbb R$ with $x_i<x_{i+1}$ be a set of cardinality $N\in\mathbb N$, and let $f:X\to X$ be a bijection.  Let $G_f$ be the graph defined as follows:

Draw one node for each $x_i$.  For any $i< j$ from $1$ to $N$, we draw an edge $e_{ij}$. If $f(x_i)<f(x_j)$, color the edge red.  If $f(x_i)>f(x_j)$, color the edge blue.

Our condition is that neither
$$
f(x_{i_1}) <f(x_{i_2}) <\dots <f(x_{i_n})
$$
nor
$$
f(x_{i_1}) >f(x_{i_2}) >\dots >f(x_{i_n})
$$
is true for any increasing selection of indices $i_k$.  This condition holds **iff $G_f$ has no monochromatic complete subgraph on $n$ nodes**.  Thus, for a given $X$, we only can find a suitable $f$ when $N<R(N,N)$.

---

With that in mind, Ramsey theory gives us the following results:

- if $n=3$, we can only find a suitable $f$ if $N<6$
- if $n=4$, we can only find a suitable $f$ if $N<18$
- if $n=5$, we can only find a suitable $f$ if $N<49$
- if $n=6$, we can only find a suitable $f$ if $N<165$

and so on and so forth, following [the diagonal entries of this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers).

Finally, as was pointed out in the comments: for any $X$ of non-finite cardinality, [the Infinite Ramsey's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem) tells us that we can find **infinitely many** (increasing) $i_k$ so that

$$
f(x_{i_1}) <f(x_{i_2}) <\dots <f(x_{i_k})<\dots
$$
or
$$
f(x_{i_1}) >f(x_{i_2}) >\dots >f(x_{i_k})>\dots
$$

---

Note: although every bijection has a corresponding graph, not every possible graph on the $N$ nodes as defined above corresponds to a possible bijection $f:X\to X$.  However, there may be a bijection for every graph [up to isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism).  At any rate, it is not clear to me whether, for example, we can find a bijection $f$ on an $X$ containing $5$ elements that will satisfy the condition for $n=3$.

---

After some investigation, it turns out that there is no suitable bijection on a set of $5$ elements.  The conditions I gave above on the number of elements in a set are thus necessary but **insufficient** to establish the existence of a suitable bijection.

Answer (score 7):

No need to bring in Ramsey theory!
Given such a function $f$, consider the sequence
$$
f\left(1 - \tfrac{1}{2} \right),\;
f\left(1 - \tfrac{1}{3} \right),\;
f\left(1 - \tfrac{1}{4} \right), \ldots
$$
As [any sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a monotone subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716461/proof-verification-every-sequence-in-bbb-r-contains-a-monotone-sub-sequence), there exists an increasing sequence of real numbers $x_i$, $0 < x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \cdots$, such that
$$
f(x_1) \le f(x_2) \le f(x_3) \le \cdots
\text{ or }
f(x_1) \ge f(x_2) \ge f(x_3) \ge \cdots
$$
and since $f$ is a bijection, equality cannot hold, i.e.
$$
f(x_1) < f(x_2) < f(x_3) < \cdots
\text{ or }
f(x_1) > f(x_2) > f(x_3) > \cdots
$$
so the rearrangement you ask for is impossible for any $n$.